# JWT token is always throwing ExpiredJwtException while parsing in java

Tags: java, jwt

I'm trying to implement jwt based authentication to expose my REST api using spring boot, but I'm facing an issue with JWT expiration date.It is always throwing "ExpiredJwtException" even i have set expiration time. I have provided code, please let me know if someone find exact issue and solution. Thanks.

git repository https://github.com/asim-ch/JWT-authentication-with-spring-boot

**Authentication Filter**

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

   @Autowired
   TokenProvider tokenProvider;
   @Autowired
   CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, 
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws 
    ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwt(httpServletRequest);
            if (jwt!=null && tokenProvider.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = tokenProvider.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication
                        = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Can NOT set user authentication ", e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    private String getJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return authHeader.replace("Bearer ","");
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**TokenProvider class**

```
package com.example.RestApi.Configs;
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
public class TokenProvider {


    private String jwtSecret = "something";
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenProvider.class);
    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Date d = new Date();
        Date expiry = new Date(d.getTime() + 720000L);
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();

        final String authorities = userPrincipal.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername()))
                .setIssuedAt(d)
                .claim("roles", authorities)
                .setExpiration(expiry)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();
        return token;
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        String userName = null;
        try {
            userName = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody().getSubject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return userName;
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
                    .parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.debug("signature exception"+e);
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
           logger.debug("token malformed"+e);

        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
           logger.debug("token expired"+e);

        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.debug("unsupported"+e);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.debug("Illegal"+e);

        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

**Exception Facing**

[In validateToken() mehode I'm always getting this exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu57C.png)

Comment: Seems its working as expected. As per screen shot you mentioned, token is already expired on "1/10" and you are trying it on "3/10". Can you regenerate new token and try again?

Comment: @ShaunakPatel please consider the expiry date i have appended to the token in TokensProvider class and i didn't set "1/10" anywhere even after regenerating token i'm facing the same issue expiry date is always "1/10"

Comment: @Asimshahzad for me your code works fine as i checked, so check your system date or somewhere you are setting date in your application which might be generating old date.

Comment: @kj007 there is no any other code script in my app which is dealing with token expiry time besides it. And my system time is also correct, whenever i run the code the expiry time is always 1/10.

Comment: how you are generating new token?

Comment: @ShaunakPatel I'm using "JJWT" and generating token by myself through "Jwts.builder()" method, please check the method "genrateJwtToken()" in "TokenProvider" class in the code section.

Comment: @Asimshahzad can you check your system date match with current time ??

Comment: @Asimshahzad can you debug your code and check at token generation time what time your Date object return before adding expire time..

Comment: @kj007 yes system time is as it is as current time showing in the snap while debugging.

Comment: @Asimshahzad can you show me one token generated, share complete Bearer string..and if possible please share demo code on github, let me look at as I can see your code for generating token works fine as checked ..

Comment: @kj007 yes sure here is the token
"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhc2FkIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM4NjcyMjg2LCJyb2xlcyI6IlJPTEVfQURNSU4sUk9MRV9VU0VSLFJPTEVfQURNSVNTSU9OIiwiZXhwIjoxNTM4NjcyNDA2fQ.jjkeOgHHuFbQGklyEUC23Ta4apiJRBmYlZY1KeiWlY_Adqmz5aTyPMd82MtmR34TLFEF80xqg4A7UotlNHwZpw"

Comment: Your token is correctly generated as it says expire time Oct 04, 2018 22:30:06 IST

Comment: Yes but while parsing that token on server side it is expired at 1/10. I am pushing my repo to github and will provide you link soon

Comment: @kj007 If you want to look into it then please consider this git repo. https://github.com/asim-ch/JWT-authentication-with-spring-boot

Comment: @Asimshahzad, I just tried to execute your code and its working as expected. Not sure why you are getting error.

Comment: @Asimshahzad are you still facing issue after using system. Milliseconds, add five min more by multiplying 5 as might be because of two min window you are checking after two min, try and let me know as your code works fine for me.

Comment: @ShaunakPatel still I'm getting that exception and I'm wondering that it is working in your case. What if i don't set any expiry date ?

Comment: @kj007 i tried everything i think problem is with my system but i don't know any, b/c system date is correct while generating token .

Comment: Try mvn clean install if Incase there is any conflict

Comment: After Invalidating cache and restarting intellij it's working. Thanks guyz for your time.

Comment: @Asimshahzad great, I have posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine as tested by me too.

So try of couple of things

1. Do clean install by command line `mvn clean install`
2. Remove m2 repository and then again import dependencies
3. Try removing cache and restart IDE and system

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Tried @kj007 answer. However it didn't work for me.

In my case it was an [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) bug. After restarting it, everything was ok. I deem somehow it was sending an old token.